# ¿Hay bibliotecas que faltan en nltk.sem?

Tags: python, nltk

Quería diseñar patrones que sean sensibles a etiquetas de Part-Of-Speech (POS) de la sección holandesa de CoNLL 2002 Named Entity Corpus que entonces no contiene solo la anotación de entidad nombrada. Sin embargo el método `show_clause()` quien se supone imprimir las relaciones en una forma clausal, donde el símbolo de relación binaria se especifica como el valor del parámetro relsym, no parece ser parte de `nltk.sem`. Sin embargo, parecía haber sido utilizado con éxito en [Natural Language Processing with Python](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/IT%20Various/natural_language_processing_with_python.pdf#page=307).

```
>>> for doc in conll2002.chunked_sents('ned.train'):
...     for r in nltk.sem.extract_rels('PER', 'ORG', doc,corpus='conll2002', pattern=VAN):
...         print nltk.sem.show_clause(r, relsym="VAN")
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'show_clause'
```

Es lo mismo para `show_raw_rtuple(rel, lcon=True, rcon=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El ejemplo que muestras es para la versión 2 de NLTK pero usas la NLTK 3.x. Ambas funciones fueron renombrados en la versión 3 de NLTK:

- `show_raw_rtuple()` -> `rtuple()`
- `show_clause()`     -> `clause()`

Estas funciones están definidas en el módulo [`nltk.sem.relextract`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.sem.html#module-nltk.sem.relextract) por si quieres ver la documentación, aunque se pueden acceder mediante `nltk.sem.clause` y `nltk.sem.rtuple` gracias a que son expuestas en el paquete mediante el `__init__.py`.